# What are the reasons a NullPointerException could be thrown in this ternary statement?

Tags: java

The following code throws a `NullPointerException` during the return statement.

```java
private Integer[] intLeftToRight;

private boolean isConditionSatisfied(int keyIndex, Integer rangeNumber) {
    return rangeNumber == null ? true : (intLeftToRight[keyIndex] >= rangeNumber);
}
```

Since it is difficult to debug this particular program, I'm trying to determine what are *all* of the reasons such an exception could be thrown on that line? So far I've come up with following. Do any others exist?

1. `intLeftToRight` is null
2. `intLeftToRight[keyIndex]` is null

Comment: Note that this would be slightly more readable as `return (rangeNumber == null) || (i[k] >= rangeNumber)`.

Comment: Just curious but if 'rangeNumber' is null, won't the ternary expression return true right away ? or will it still evaluate the right hand side expression and cause an exception, as @JustAnotherDeveloper just said ?
And as keyIndex is a primitive type, I don't think it can be null here

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper `rangeNumber` is checked for `null` in the code, and `keyIndex` is an `int`, so it can't be 0.

Comment: Those two are the only two reasons why a NPE would be thrown at that line. Of course, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown if `keyIndex >= intLeftToRight.length`.

Comment: the code is equivalent to
`if( rangeNumber == null ) return true;  return intLeftToRight[keyIndex] >= rangeNumber;`

Comment: The two are the only points for `NPE`. But, rather than ternary, why not  `return (rangeNumber == null || intLeftToRight[keyIndex] >= rangeNumber);`